# How to send data to word document in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, cpu-word

[image]

As you can see in the above image I have `EditText` and a `Button`.

[image]

This is a Word Document. And here I have a heading `Name` and a placeholder `{name}`. So, what I want is that If user enters his/her name (From the app) then it should extract the data(that I know how to do it) and replace it with the placeholder(that I wanna know how to do it).

Is their any way or an API?

Comment: If I have understood your question correctly ... you want the heading to be updated when user tries to enter the the name say I write something in edittext it should reflect as user write ?

Comment: @AgentP , I want the placeholder text to get replaced by what user has enter in editText Field.

Comment: Harsha I have deleted my answer ... Since it wasn't addressed actuall issue  update your question with that detail do that other can know it too

Comment: Thanks. I have updated my question , Do you know someone who can help?

Comment: I don't understand your problem, are you trying to open a Word document in your app? have you googled it?

Comment: @MDP  I am trying to editText text or data from android to word Document at a particular place or placeholder.

Comment: Are you using Docx4J? https://www.docx4java.org/trac/docx4j

Comment: @MDP No, and I have no Idea regarding Docx4j.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with sockets connections. You emit an event from the phone client (Android), receive it in your server, and emit it again to your desktop client.

There's a [Word Javascript API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/overview/word-add-ins-reference-overview) that can help you with accesing a Word document

For the sockets implementation, you can use [SocketIO](https://socket.io/) for both clients (desktop and mobile) and the server.